# Magento: sending password email notification every day to customers with new passwords automacally. How to disable this?

Tags: magento

Magento:

shop customers are getting email notification with new password every day automacally.

How to disable this automatic email notification on magento site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please check if your magento setup can contain cron to set each day new email password in your server,

Or one another alternative i would like to suggest here to install this plugin to [disable email notification](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/disable-email-notifications-8993.html) it is free and easy to install to disable your notification regarding email to customer.

hope this would be good solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked on magento setup cron is set. i deleted the cron now i have to check tomorrow mails are getting or not.

Comment: @Venkat, welcome. if my answer is useful will please accept it so some one can utilize our thread in future if they have same issue,

Comment: After i disable corn job having price and product discrepancies occurring so again i enabled the corn job and i tried to install "disable email notification module" but unable to do it. i generated extension key and i tried to install through magneto connect using  Paste extension key to install it and its throwing Couldn't resolve host 'magneto-community' error please advise to resolve this issue